# oval shape to circle Postgres , Postgis

Tags: laravel, postgresql, openlayers, postgis

I need to convert oval shape to circle

```
SELECT parcel_id, ST_AsGeoJSON(st_buffer(ST_centroid(geometry), 0.01)) as buffer from data_landuse.ca_landuse_type1_tbl where parcel_id = '$id'
```

this query show layer on the map but it doesn't I was expecting. It shows an oval shape in the map how to show a circle on the map ?

Comment: You are probably using longitude and latitude as coordinates. One degree of longitude is not the same as one degree of latitude, hence the oval shape. Use a different coordinate system.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe like what? I don't know the different coordinate system and I am newbie to this ahahaha

Comment: It depends on where you are and what requirements you have.